# "Always on Top" disabled for maximized windows

Tags: gnome, xorg

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Desktop: GNOME
Session: gnome-xorg
When a window is maximized, the option "Always on Top" (AoT) is disabled. Is this supposed to be a feature or a bug?
What is the logic behind it?

The reason why I am asking and it doesn't make sense to me is the following:
I have an application with multiple windows (like the GIMP in old days...). I set these to be on top, as it makes working easier.

Sometimes, I want to switch to Firefox (FF) to check something up... FF is always maximized.
Either, I have to disable AoT on all those windows (tedious) or I have to set FF to be also AoT. Then I can bring it in front of the other application.

Since FF is maximized, I have to unmaximize the windows, enable AoT and maximize again, which seems to be unnecessarily tedious. And it works. So technically, there is nothing wrong with a window being maximized and AoT at the same time.
Any ideas why? Does it happen on your systems too?

Comment: you should make use of workspaces. This is exactly what it's for.

Comment: @RoVo not if I want to see the other application in the background. But in my case this helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a "feature". When a window is maximized, and then you also want to put it always on top, you are essentially in a way disabling your entire desktop. You can't switch to another window anymore. To to some extent, this "protects" less experienced users. However, I agree with you that this should not be a reason to disable the setting when the window is full screen, but here it is.

However, Gnome Shell out of the box offers alternate paradigms to achieve what you want.

1) Merely switching using Alt+tab, clicking Gimp in the dash, or searching and selecting it in the overview will bring all Gimp Windows at once in the front. Switching to Firefox will bring your full screen firefox to the front. So no need to temporarily turn on and turn off "set Windows always on front", even with a multi-windowed gimp. One standard task switching operation is sufficient.

2) It gets better if you use your Desktops! Put your multi-window Gimp on a separate workspace. Switch to Gimp any way (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, clicking the dash, searching it in the overview), and you will immediately be transferred to Gimp with all its windows neatly laid out, unobstructed by other windows, with your nice wallpaper behind. Alt+Tab again, and you are in your full screen Firefox. With desktops, you have an additional way to switch tasks, so you could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow up/down</kbd> to switch between the two in their own separated visual context.

Comment: I don't fully agree with it. Especially, when I need to work between 2 applications (e.g. FF and <x>) it makes sense FF to be maximized in the background (maybe even to play some videos, while the other application is on top of FF covering it partially.
ad Option 1) when many applications are open, this can get tedious too.
ad Option 2) Yes, this would be the solution for me. Therefore, I accept it. However, the scenario, where I want to play a video in the background, doesn't work with workspaces.