# Always on top is reset when the window is maximized in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I had to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS since Ubuntu 16 is close to EOL.

It's been quite an unpleasant experience (CTRL+Shift for switching between languages is not allowed - ancient bug - will give me a tic for sure).

I'm particularly bothered by the fact that "Always on top" window feature gets disabled when I maximize the window. The tick in the window properties is still there but the window loses the actual quality of being on top.

I've also enabled "Always on visible workspace" but it did not resolve the issue completely.

I need my Thunderbird mail always on top. I maximize it from time to time to read or mark read something but after minimizing (taking only part of the screen) the mailbox window gotta stay on top 100% of the time.

This was not an issue in Ubuntu 16.04 at all. I have searched and searched but I cannot find the solution for this.

Please help. Is there some workaround?

Update: Here is a very similar issue ["Always on Top" disabled for maximized windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122921/always-on-top-disabled-for-maximized-windows) but the solution for this specific situation was not found.

Comment: I am confused if it is full screen is it not by default always on top?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.10. A window that is always on top, remains so when maximized and unmaximized again. Did you do a fresh install, or did you upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 then to 20.04?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I do need to clarify. I put the window with Thunderbird in the bottom right corner of the screen to see only the folders. In this state I want it to be on top of the browser window (which is fullscreen). But I often maximize the Thunderbird window to read. When I drag the Thunderbird window back to taking only part of the screen, it loses its "on top" quality, meaning that when I click on the browser window in the background, Thunderbird gets hidden.

Comment: I did upgrade from 16.0 ->> 18 > 20.04. It's not a fresh install. But I made sure to remove all the unnecessary packages with Ubuntu Cleaner.